# unix cat multiple files - don't cause error if one doesn't exist?

Tags: file, unix, concatenation

I'm trying to cat a bunch of files, some of which may not exist. Now that's ok if some of them don't exist, but I don't want cat to return an error in this case, if possible. Here's my call:

```
zcat *_max.rpt.gz *_min.rpt.gz | gzip > temp.rpt.gz
```

When this command is run, either a bunch of files matching *_max.rpt.gz will exist, or *_min.rpt.gz will exist. If the other doesn't exist, I don't care, I just want to concatenate what I can. But I'm getting an error message which stops the rest of my code from running.

Anything I can do? Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just redirect the stderr to /dev/null:

```
cat file1 file2 .... 2>/dev/null
```

If one or more files don't exist, then cat will give an error which will go to /dev/null and you'll get the desired result.

Comment: my man... I knew people used /dev/null for something. EDIT - not sure where to put 2>/dev/null in my line of code - after the pipe or before?

Comment: @YoungMoney Before the pipe: `zcat *_max.rpt.gz *_min.rpt.gz 2>/dev/null | gzip > temp.rpt.gz`

Comment: `cat` will return a **non-zero exit code** if it can't find one of the input files.

Answer (score 12):

`[ -f file.txt ] && cat file.txt`

Answer (score 8):

```
grep -hs ^ file1 file2 ....
```

Unlike cat has zero return code. Option -h disables file name print, option -s disables file error reporting, ^ matches all lines.

Comment: On bash 4.2 I get error code 2 for `grep -hs ^ missing_file`

Answer (score 5):

You can append `|| True` to your commands to silence the exit code.

Answer (score 1):

```
zcat `ls *.rpt.gz | grep -E '_(max|min)\.rpt\.gz$'` | gzip > temp.rpt.gz
```

Bit of a hack, but then so is the shell :-P